# Assigning to struct in different class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a struct in ClassA and want to assign it to the same struct in ClassB (the two structs are the same with different names).  ClassA and ClassB are view controllers.  Basically, I need to pass this struct to another class. However, structs don't seem to be exposed as members, which means I can't access them.  Here is ClassA's struct declared in its header file:

```
typedef struct {
NSString *startDate;
NSString *endDate;
NSString *classId;
}  selectedItemsClassAStruct;

selectedItemsClassAStruct selectedItemsClassA;
```

and the same for ClassB (just with ClassA text replaced)

It doesn't appear in code hints for ClassB.  I see this error if I try to access it:

```
request for member 'selectedItemsClassBStruct' in something not a structure or union
```

How should it be done?

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is called re-interpreting cast or type punning; which means changing one structure into another structure that have the same members.

This trick is used by Cocoa to convert a `NSRect` into a `CGRect` for example.

I recommend the reading of a [good post](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/04/using-pointers-to-recast-in-c-is-bad.html) on the subject written by [Matt Gallagher](http://cocoawithlove.com/).

Answer (score 0):

[Matt Gallagher](http://cocoawithlove.com/) describes how to (safely) implement properties for structs in [this post](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/10/memory-and-thread-safe-custom-property.html).